# Dimension of the kernel of a linear transformation of an eigenbasis

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let V be a vector space of dimension n and let $T: V \to V$ be a linear transformation. Assume
> $T$ has eigenvalues $λ_1, λ_2,\dots, λ_n$. For each $j = 1, 2, \dots, n$, let $b_j$ be an eigenvector of $T$ associated to $λ_j$. Assume $B = \{b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n\}$ is a basis of $V$ (one calls $B$ an eigenvector basis for $T$). Therefore, $T(b_j) = λ_jb_j$ for $1 ≤ j ≤ n$. Now, assume $λ_j \neq 0$ for all $j$. Find the dimension of the kernel of $T$. Justify your answer.

I am a little confused with this question. In my understanding, since $b_j$ is a basis vector, it can't be $0$, and since $λ_j \neq 0$, then $λ_jb_j$ cannot equal zero. Does that mean that the null space of $T$ does not exist? In that case, is $\dim(\ker(T))=0$?
Thanks!

Comment: The argument by itself does not suffice: you are trying to say that because the image of each basis vector is not zero then the kernel is trivial. But that isn’t usually true: for instance, $T\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $T(a,b)=(a+b,a+b)$ has nontrivial kernel (e.g., $(1,-1)$ is in the kernel), but if we apply $T$ to the standard basis we get $T(1,0)\neq (0,0)$ and $T(0,1)\neq (0,0)$. So you need more than what you’ve given to reach the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $v\in\ker(T)$. Let $v=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_jb_j$. Then $$T(v)=T\left(\sum_{j=1}^na_jb_j\right)=\sum_{j=1}^n a_jT(b_j)=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\lambda_jb_j=\vec{0} $$ Since $B$ is a basis, then it is linearly independent, so the scalars $a_j\lambda_j=0$ for all $1\leq j\leq n$. Since $\lambda_j\neq 0$ for all $1\leq j\leq n$, then $a_j=0$ for all $j$ which implies that $v=\vec{0}$, hence $\dim\ker(T)=0$.